# Integrating product of powers of tangent and secant

Tags: calculus, integration

In integrating trigonometric integrals of the form:

$\int{\sec^m{x}\tan^n{x}}dx$

where $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, an exact definite method were known as written in any integral calculus books when (a) the power of $\sec{x}$ is even, that is when $m$ is even and (b) the power of $\tan{x}$ is odd, that is if $n$ is odd.

However, given an integral of the same form as above but with $m$ odd and $n$ even such as :

$\int{\sec^3{x}\tan^4{x}}dx$

what I must do in order to solve this type of integral is not clear cut (for me).

My question is: Is there a definite method to integrate integrals of the for as above with $m$ odd and $n$ even? If so, what is it.

Thank you in advance for your help and answers.

Comment: Maybe my answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435755/integral-of-trig-functions/1435829#1435829 helps?

Comment: Integration by parts will work, or you can apply a reduction formula which results from integration by parts.